# Performing regex on files stored in directory

Tags: linux, oracle, bash, email, plsql

I have the following code

```
#!/bin/bash
v=""
echo "Please enter your email id"
    read em
$mai=`sqlplus -s abc/xyz << EOF
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('$em','[^_]+', 1, 1) FROM..    
for f in "$em"*
do
    echo "Processing $f file";
#mail -a $f -s " Test" $em < /dev/null
v=$v" -a "$f
done
mail $v  -s " Test" "$em"< /dev/null
```

So I am generating a file and saving it in directory

File is being saved in following format : "**abc@gmail.com_xyz_abc_123.csv**"
In the code iam extracting the email id but how call that  directory which shall look for this input?.
My issue is how to call this file using pl/sql command
Is it possible?? If no then any better solution you could suggest!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to remove all the part after the first `_` this can be done with variable expansion:

```
echo "${em%%_*}"
```

- %% : to strip the longest suffix
- _* : matching '_*'

But an email address may contain an underscore.

Comment: well yes but in my case there cannot be any email with  sing
My question is just like we do select regex <......> from table ... Here how am i supposed  check the directory . Instead of checking table I need to check directory but i need to check it using PL/SQL